# В чем разница между абсолютным путем и путем начинающимся из домашнего каталога (с символа ~)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash  
sysdir=$1

dir="dir"

case $dir in
        dir) 
        cd $sysdir
        foldername=$(basename $sysdir) 
        backupname=$foldername$date 

     cd ..
     stf_b="tar -czvpf /home/pc/script/backup/$backupname.tar.gz $foldername"
     $stf_b



    ;;

    file) 
     echo "Ok"
    ;;
esac
```

если эту строку

```
stf_b="tar -czvpf /home/pc/script/backup/$backupname.tar.gz $foldername
```

заменить на эту

```
stf_b="tar -czvpf ~/script/backup/$backupname.tar.gz $foldername
```

ничего не работает, собственно может кто объяснить почему?

Comment: может быть Вы запускаете скрипт от имени другого пользователя? например из под крона?

Comment: Нет, от имени пользователя, я просто захожу в этот же скрипт, меняют эти строки и одна работает а вторая нет, запускаю одинаково.

Comment: @S1lllver как именно запускаете? Я не вижу "магической строки" в начале скрипта

Comment: сделал правку, она там есть иначе как бы я его запустил 
./script testdir/test

Comment: @S1lllver а добавьте ка в начало скрипта `cd ~` и `pwd`. Дабы очевидные вещи отсечь.

Comment: Just use `/home/$USER`

Comment: `man tar`, в частности `-C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из стандарта POSIX

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the
> literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the
> exception of the characters dollar sign, backquote, and backslash,
>
> ...
>
> The application shall ensure that a double-quote is preceded by a
> backslash to be included within double-quotes. The parameter '@' has
> special meaning inside double-quotes

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) конкретно про тильду

> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted tilde character at the beginning of a word.......
>
> !!!! **unquoted** tilde character !!!!

Внутри двойных кавычек тильда (`~`) превращается в тыкву, т.е. просто в символ не имеющий специального значения

Оптимальный вариант, в вашем случае, добавить в самом начале скрипта

```
$MY_DIR=~
```

и потом его использовать

Comment: pc:x:1000:1000:afgan,,,:/home/pc:/bin/bash

Comment: Совпадает вроде

Comment: нет, я ошибься) поправил , все совпадает

Comment: в этом случае, если бы не совпадало.
Меня бы кидало в разные директории и я бы это заметил

<< cd /home/pc >>
<< cd ~ >>
переходит в одну директорию

Comment: @S1lllver поменял ответ

Comment: вот оно что... сейчас проверю

Comment: это ладно, а как быть то?

Comment: просто писать tar -cvpf ~/script/backup/$backupname.tar.gz $foldername , не совсем практично и удобно

Comment: @S1lllver а нахрена вам создавать переменную и потом ее запускать? Чего бы сразу не запустить, без плясок с бубном?

Comment: в скрипте много таких длинных команд я сделал CONF файл, где переменные будут хранить все эти длинные команды , а в исполняемых файлах вызывать переменные из CONF файла.

Comment: @S1lllver "It's bash, baby!" типа шутка :) Если хочется сложной логики, то perl/python в руки. Если хочется быстро и на коленке, то приходится мириться с несовершенством мира и строить костыли на шеле

Comment: @S1lllver как вариант, в самом начале забейте `HOME=~` и потом везде используйте "$HOME"

Comment: эххх, мне нужно выпить после такого )

Comment: @S1lllver "Наш человек, наш..." (с)

Comment: За ответ сделать HOME=~ и правда работает, спасибо вам добрый человек ))

Comment: @S1lllver а чему у вас $HOME равно ДО того как вы HOME=~ пытаетесь делать?