# Сервер Debian. Nginx. Настройка путей

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

Я как закостенелый пользователь Windows, не могу разобраться с написанием путей. Сайт лежит по адресу, где первым символом идет  `~`(тильда).

`nginx.conf` выглядит так:

```
.......
   server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  testSite.com;
        charset utf-8;
        location / { 
            root ~testSite/;
        }
    }
.....
```

Как результат - `Nginx` не принимает такой  путь. Как нужно написать путь, чтобы сайт заработал?

Comment: "Вообщем" - поправьте

Comment: Это вы в линуксе? Может, вы запутались и тильда на самом деле обозначала сокращение домашнего каталога /home/username, а вы не разбираясь скопипастили?) Перейдите в нужный каталог в консоли и наберите команду pwd - она напишет точный путь

Comment: для нормального ответа слишком мало данных. в общих чертах: положи свой "сайт" в /var/www/site-name и пропиши абсолютные пути. и проверь чтобы каталог мог читать юзер от имени которого запускается nginx

Comment: @andreymal не годится в качестве совета или ответа. он замучается выяснять почему nginx не может зайти в хомяк пользователя

Comment: @norbornen ну поделимся ссылками про chmod, чо :)

Comment: @norbornen кстати в линуксах права по умолчанию обычно 755/644, так что проблем возможно и не будет

Comment: @norbornen а почему тогда у меня везде права 777?) чяднт

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю. Ваш первый комментарий помог. Оформите как ответ

Comment: Я как-то не уверен как ответ оформлять, с моей точки зрения как закостенелого пользователя Linux это смахивает на опечатку) Ну или на дубликат чего-нибудь вроде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626674

Answer (score 0):

В блок server добавьте блок location следующего вида:

```
location / {
    root /data/www;
}
```

Этот блок location задаёт “/” в качестве префикса, который сравнивается с URI из запроса. Для подходящих запросов добавлением URI к пути, указанному в директиве root, то есть, в данном случае, к /data/www, получается путь к запрашиваемому файлу в локальной файловой системе. Если есть совпадение с несколькими блоками location, nginx выбирает блок с самым длинным префиксом. В блоке location выше указан самый короткий префикс, длины один, и поэтому этот блок будет использован, только если не будет совпадения ни с одним из остальных блоков location.